# ASP.NET MVC 2: Does the method OnPreAction exist in Controller class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

If it does, why can't I override it in my code?

```
protected override bool OnPreAction(string actionName, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    //do stuff

    return base.OnPreAction(actionName, methodInfo);
}
```

The posted code is in a Controller wich extends from Controller class. When I compile I get this error:

> 'Namespace.Controllers.XXController.OnPreAction(string,
>   System.Reflection.MethodInfo)': no
>   suitable method found to override

If the method doesn't exist, is there anyone which replace it?

If it does exist, whats the problem in my code?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx).

Comment: Ok. And why is that? Is OnPreAction from MVC 1?

Comment: @Diego: I think it's from a beta.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method. You probably want `OnActionExecuting`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ActionFilter attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx). You can easily [roll your own pre/post processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx) for either a single action or every action in a controller.

BTW, some standard filters based on the same mechanism are included in ASP.NET MVC, such as the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute.